# Keras Deep Neural Network gives incorrerct/constant regression line

Tags: python, keras, regression

I have created a Keras deep neural network for 2 regression models, and plotted the resulting regression lines with the actual data and predictions for the test data. I get the following plots:

[image: 1. The predictions for the test data are close to the actual data but the regression line doesn't reflect the test predictions]

[image: 2. The predictions for the test data reflects the regression line but the predictions are constant and far from the actual data]

Plot 1: The predictions for the test data are close to the actual data but the regression line doesn't reflect the test predictions.

Plot 2: The predictions for the test data reflects the regression line but the predictions are constant and far from the actual data

I trained both models the same way using the same structure, but they behave differently and neither seems correct. What could be the problem?

The code for prediction and plotting:

```
        X = df["X"]
        Y = df["Y"]

        (train, test) = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

        # scale Y
        maxY = train["Y"].max()
        trainY = train["Y"] / maxY
        testY = test["Y"] / maxY
    
        # scale X
        trainX = scalerx.fit_transform(train["X"].values.reshape(-1,1))
        testX = scalerx.fit_transform(test["X"].values.reshape(-1,1))

        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=dim, activation="relu"))
        model.add(Dense(6, activation="relu"))
        model.add(Dense(4, activation="relu"))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear"))

        opt = Adam(learning_rate=1e-2, decay=1e-3/200)
        model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_percentage_error", optimizer=opt)

        model.fit(x=trainX, y=trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY), epochs=500, batch_size=4)

        # predict regression line
        x = np.arange(0, X.max() + 0.1 , 0.01)
        preds = model.predict(scalerx.fit_transform(x.reshape(-1, 1)))
        preds = preds * maxY
        
        # predict for test data
        pred_y = model.predict(testX)
        pred_y = pred_y * maxY

        plt.scatter(X, Y, label='data')
        plt.scatter(test["X"], pred_y, label='test data')
        plt.plot(x, preds, 'r', label='regression line')
        plt.xlabel('x')
        plt.ylabel('y')
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
```

Comment: code snippet is not complete. missing many variable declarations.

Comment: You are incorrectly using the MinMaxScaler, you should fit it to the training data, and then use it (not fit it again) with the test data and new predictions (like inverse_transform). You are fitting it multiple times and this means the scale of inputs is completely wrong.

Comment: I fixed the scaling and it fixed plot 1 but plot 2 is still the same. Why does it predict a constant Y values for all X?